# Prove that T1 connected space has dimension at least 1

Tags: general-topology

The question states:

> Let X be a connected $T_1$ space such that $|X|>1$. Show that $X$ has covering dimension at least 1.

Here, covering dimension should be refering to the Lebesgue's covering dimension.

Thought process:

$T_1$ means that all singleton elements $\{x\}$ are closed. As $X$ is connected, each singleton is not open.

But then for any $x$, it just meet with $X \setminus \{x\}$. How to show that there are another refinement meeting with $x \in X$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there existed a connected $T_1$ space $X$ with covering dimension $0$ and $|X|>1$. Then by definition, if we consider an arbitrary open cover $\mathcal{V}$ of the space, then there must be some refinement $\mathcal{U}$ of it with order $1$ - in other words, that every point in the space $X$ belongs to at most a single open set of $\mathcal{U}$.

This implies that it is possible to have a family of disjoint open sets covering $X$, but since $X$ is connected, it must be that only one such set is non-empty. Thus, the only possible refinement of $\mathcal{V}$ meeting the criteria is $\{X\}$. So it is then required that $\{X\}\subseteq\mathcal{V}$ for every open cover $\mathcal{V}$, but this is impossible since if we consider distinct $x,y\in X$, by the $T_1$ property it must be that $\{X\setminus\{x\},X\setminus\{y\}\}$ forms an open cover of this space without $\{X\}$ as a refinement.

This leaves the only possibility that there are no two distinct points in $X$, i.e. that $|X|=1$. But this is in contradiction with the hypothesis. Hence, no such space with covering dimension $0$ exists, so the dimension of $X$ must at least be $1$.